# Headless Wordpress, Is there a way to access data in wp_options table as REST endpoint?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, headless-cms

Wordpress has an awesome REST API interface.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/

But the content in wp_options table seems to be missing REST support. Is there a way to access the content in wp_otions table as REST endpoint via plugins?. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [`settings`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/) endpoint, but it only contains a surprisingly limited amount of them it seems.

This is something you could very easily do yourself though. I'm not sure if any plugins do it, but I also wouldn't recommend a plugin for something that can be done with less than 20 lines of code.

You just need to register a route using [`register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) on the [`rest_api_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_api_init/) hook, and pass it a callback function. You can drop code like this in your `functions.php` file or create a [Must Use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) and drop the code in there, either way.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'my-custom-route/v1', '/opt/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_rest_option',
        //'permission_callback' => function () {
        //  return current_user_can( 'administrator' );
        //}
    ) );
} );

function get_rest_option( $data ) {
    return get_option( $data['option_name'] );
}
```

The above will give you access to whatever option you want by accessing:

```
/wp-json/my-custom-route/v1/opt/?option_name=siteurl
```

I went ahead and dropped an example on a site of mine:

https://xhynk.com/content-mask/wp-json/my-custom-route/v1/opt/?option_name=blogname
https://xhynk.com/content-mask/wp-json/my-custom-route/v1/opt/?option_name=siteurl

However, this will potentially expose *anything* in your options table. I went ahead and commented out the `permission_callback` so that any person, signed in or not, can access it. However, I also added a check like this:

```
function get_rest_option( $data ) {
    if( $data['option_name'] === 'siteurl' || $data['option_name'] === 'blogname' ){
        return get_option( $data['option_name'] );
    } else {
        return 'Unauthorized. Use `siteurl` or `blogname`';
    }
}
```

You can see that `home` will fail: https://xhynk.com/content-mask/wp-json/my-custom-route/v1/opt/?option_name=home

I would recommend adding in a valid array of options, or using the `permission_callback` in order to lock it down a bit. You could even have an access key instead, and keep that key secret. Either way, be aware of the security implications of exposing your entire `wp_options` table, and take *some* sort of preventative measure!

Comment: Is this still true in 2022?

Comment: I believe so. A quick search didn't show a way for options (either native WordPress, or added via themes, plugins, etc.) to be exposed in the API. The API exposes self documentation if you visit the index page (example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/) and there's no reference in there I see either.

Comment: Oke - thanks for having a peek for me. I also checked with woocommerce and the api gives access to some settings pertaining woocommerce but does not expose the entire wp_options table, so it seems like this approach is still valid.